# How to display data date MYSQL /2 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have table in DB like this

[dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a0577c43572b8273bbc0fa3d1e34e67)

i want to display the data order by date / 2 hours

for example

```
HF01245523 | 2019-11-17 06:01:05 | 1.10513 | 599
HF01245043 | 2019-11-17 04:01:06 | 1.10513 | 599
HF01244562 | 2019-11-17 02:00:06 | 1.10513 | 599
```

Is that possible?

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT MAX(tgl_harga) AS maxdate
    FROM tbl_dummy
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR(tgl_harga), 
        MONTH(tgl_harga), 
        WEEK(tgl_harga), 
        DAY(tgl_harga) 
) AS g 
INNER JOIN tbl_dummy ON g.maxdate = tbl_dummy.tgl_harga
```

But this query just display /day, I dont know to display records /2 hours.

Comment: So do you want to *filter* the data to show only one record every 2 hours? Or is it something else that you are looking for?

Comment: @GMB yes, i want to show only every 2 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your existing query, you can do date arithmetic. Consider:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
    SELECT MAX(tgl_harga) AS maxdate
    FROM tbl_dummy
    GROUP BY 
        DATE(tgl_harga), 
        FLOOR(HOUR(tgl_harga) / 2)
) AS g 
INNER JOIN tbl_dummy t ON g.maxdate = t.tgl_harga
ORDER BY t.tgl_harga DESC
```

This gives you one record for each fixed 2 hour window, which is the latest record in that window (so: one record between 0h and 2h, one record between 2h and 4h, and so on). Note that this does not necessarily mean that the records in the resultset will have a 2 hour spacing between them.

In your **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56db01d72766235e0af6d23e8c2266cf)**, the query produces:

```
id_harga   | tgl_harga           |   harga | id_region
:--------- | :------------------ | ------: | :--------
HF01245523 | 2019-11-17 06:01:05 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01245515 | 2019-11-17 05:59:07 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01245035 | 2019-11-17 03:59:06 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01244554 | 2019-11-17 01:57:06 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01244082 | 2019-11-16 23:59:06 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01243602 | 2019-11-16 21:59:06 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01243114 | 2019-11-16 19:57:07 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01242642 | 2019-11-16 17:59:06 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01242162 | 2019-11-16 15:59:07 | 1.10513 | 599      
HF01241682 | 2019-11-16 13:59:06 | 1.10513 | 599
```

Comment: James Harden my Idola xD 


i try change your query to show data every 10 minutes, but it's doesn't work 

    SELECT t.* FROM (
        SELECT MAX(tgl_harga) AS maxdate
        FROM tbl_dummy
        GROUP BY 
            DATE(tgl_harga), 
            FLOOR(MINUTES(tgl_harga) / 10)
    ) AS g 
    INNER JOIN tbl_dummy t ON g.maxdate = t.tgl_harga
    ORDER BY t.tgl_harga DESC

Comment: Make it: `FLOOR((HOUR(tgl_harga) * 60 + MINUTE(tgl_harga)) / 10)`